# What members of the enclosing class can a static nested class access?

Tags: java, inner-classes

1. Java The Complete Reference says

   > A static nested class is one that has the static modifier applied. Because it is static, **it must access the non-static
   >   members of its enclosing class through an object**. That is, **it
   >   cannot refer to non-static members of its enclosing class
   >   directly**. Because of this restriction, static  nested classes are
   >   seldom used.

   What does it mean by "through an object", and "cannot ... directly"?
2. Java in a Nutshell says

   > • A static member type can access **(only) the  static  members of the class that contains it**.
   >
   > • A  static  member  type  has  access  to  all  the  static   members  (including  any other static member types) of its
   >   containing type.

   Are the two sentences redundant to each other? What are the differences between the two sentences?
3. Do the quotes from the two books contradict each other? The first
   quote says a static nested class can access non-static member of the
   enclosing class, while the second quote says a static member type
   can access only the static members of the enclosing class.

Thanks.

Comment: _What does it mean by "through an object"_ == through an instance of the enclosing class. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks. can you show how to do that "through an instance of the enclosing class"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java nested non - static classes have a hidden reference to the instance of the parent class. That's why they can access all non-static members.  The nested class doesn't have such an instance. However, its scope allows it to access the parent members if the parent class passes **this**.

So what the second quote is saying that the access doesn't happen automatically. You pass the reference to the enclosing class and the nested static class can access it. Otherwise, it doesn't know the address of the enclosing class.

Comment: Thanks. can you show how to make the parent class pass `this`?

Comment: Just call a method passing this as a parameter.  Eg.  ```Inner x = new Inner(this)``` where the constructor for Inner is defined like ```Inner(Outer y) { someOuterObject = y; }```.

Answer (score 0):

No static method may access an instance field directly without first qualifying it with an object of the containing class.

```java
class Foo {
   int myField;

   public void main(String[] args) {
       Foo foo = new Foo();
       access(foo);
   }
   public static void access(Foo obj) {
      System.out.println(myField); // <-- error, can't access myField from static 
                                   //context.
      System.out.println(obj.myField); // OK here  
   }
}
```

The same is true for accessing instance fields via inner static classes.

Answer (score 0):

A java static nested class can access the static members of the nested class and the static members of the parent class. This makes sense when you understand the position of a class and object in memory – that there is only one class but multiple objects and you need to decide what each instance of an object needs absolutely necessarily and what is actually redundant and can stay in the class (doesn't need to be duplicated), so all methods (static and non static) and all static members

Answer (score 0):

> What members of the enclosing class can a static nested class access?

You can gain clarity to the answer for this question by assigning the following meaning for the Java keyword *static*:

"Static" in Java means *without regard for or association with any instance of any class*.

- A **static field** belongs to the class in which it is declared and is not encapsulated by any instance of that class.  Any instance of the class that is subsequently constructed (or any instance or any method of any class that is in scope) can access the static field (this is why static fields can be dangerous in concurrent environments).
- A **static method** is defined for the class in which it is declared and has no associated instance of that class.  A static method knows of no class instances and can not access any of them unless a reference to an instance is passed to it as an argument.
- A **static member class** is in every way that matters the same as an ordinary top level class that has been packaged within an enclosing class for packaging convenience.  Just like a top level class, its instances know nothing of any instance of the enclosing class (unless a reference to an enclosing class instance is passed to them during construction).
- A **static initializer block** is used to initialize static fields for a class, but it knows nothing of any instances of that class.  Therefore, they cannot initialize instance fields since they cannot access them.

Therefore, the answer becomes intuitive: a static nested class can access all members of an enclosing class that can be accessed without an instance of that class.

If an enclosing class instance is passed to the static nested class's constructor, then the members of that instance (including the private ones) will be in scope. Logically, passing an enclosing class instance to a static nested class constructor is very similar to using a nested member class.  The difference is that for the former, the association is an explicit dependency injection; whereas for the latter, the association between instances is implicit.